# What is the backend process of a terraform script for associating a Azure NSG

Tags: terraform

The script given below works fine. But the problem is that when I give Terraform apply the second time it disassociates the NSG from the subnets. And when I apply again it associates to the subnets. Is there any problem with my code or what does this line actually does maybe that will solve my problem.

```
network_security_group_id = 
"${element(azurerm_network_security_group.NetworkSG.*.id,count.index)}"
```

The below code is my main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "Subnet" {
count                     = "${length(var.Subnet_name)}"
name                      = "${var.Subnet_name[count.index]}"
virtual_network_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.Vnet.name}"
resource_group_name       = 
"${azurerm_resource_group.ResourceGroup.name}"
address_prefix            = 
"${element(var.Subnet_range[var.Subnet_name[count.index]], 0)}"
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "NetworkSG" {
  count  =  "${length(var.Subnet_name)}"
  name                = 
"${element(var.Subnet_range[var.Subnet_name[count.index]], 1)}"
  location            = 
"${azurerm_resource_group.ResourceGroup.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ResourceGroup.name}"
}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" 
"NetworkSGassociation" {
count= "${length(var.Subnet_name)}"
subnet_id = "${element(azurerm_subnet.Subnet.*.id, count.index)}"
network_security_group_id = 
"${element(azurerm_network_security_group.NetworkSG.*.id,count.index)}" 
}
```

Below is my .tfvars file:

```
Subnet_name= ["SCB-Sub1","SCB-Sub2","SCB-Sub3"]
Subnet_range =
{
    SCB-Sub1= ["10.10.0.0/24","SCB-nsg1"]
    SCB-Sub2= ["10.10.1.0/24","SCB-nsg2"]
    SCB-Sub3= ["10.10.2.0/24","SCB-nsg3"]
}
```

This is the output I get when I use terraform plan:

`azurerm_subnet.Subnet[1]: Modifying... (ID: 
/subscriptions/0000-...tualNetworks/SCB_vnet/subnets/SCB-Sub3) 
network_security_group_id: "/subscriptions/0000/resourceGroups/SCB- 
rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/SCB-nsg3" => ""`

Comment: What does your plan look like for both when it disassociates and associates the NSG?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR  After associating if I give terraform plan it shows this  `azurerm_subnet.Subnet[1]: Modifying... (ID: /subscriptions/0000-...tualNetworks/SCB_vnet/subnets/SCB-Sub3)
  network_security_group_id: "/subscriptions/0000/resourceGroups/SCB-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/SCB-nsg3" => ""`

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of the plans instead of trying to fit it in a comment.